# how to create a httpGate with Obserservable

Tags: angular, switch-statement, observable, httpclient, angular-http-interceptors

I have multiple requests which I want to pause until the authenticate http request has been confirm. This means I should have a http gate which request can go thru without having to auth and some will wait until authenticate token comes back.

I thought of using switchmap like below code but then it will not work because a observable switch with a return value.

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
 return next.handle(req)
  .switchMap((event: HttpEvent<any>, index: number): Observable<HttpEv

ent<any>> => {

// without the **req.url.indexOf('/index')>-1**
//// Error Meassage: ***You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.***

   if(this.token || req.url.indexOf('/index')>-1) {
    return Observable.of(event);
   }
  })
  .do(
   next: function(data){
    console.log(data);
   },
   error: function(error: HttpErrorResponse){
    // retry
    // or handling data
   }
  );
```

Error MESSAGE

**You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of do it from `intercept()`, I would recommend you create your own `ApiService`, expose a few methods and make all of your HTTP calls from there.

Inside your `ApiService`, you could have for example:

```
Get(url: string): Observable {
  return of(0).pipe(
    switchMap(() => this.waitForAuth()),
    switchMap(() => this.$http.get(url))
  );
}
```

So every time you call your endpoint, your request will hang there until the user is authenticated. Or it'll make the call immediately if the user is already authenticated.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, Xinan. I need to keep the intercept pattern unless this is my last resort because of time and restructuring majority of the codes which I don’t have the liberty to change. Could I use inner observable to control outer observable and any stream that comes into this will pause?